# React useEffect (with []) is called every time I change page (React Router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I prepared small demo for the problem:

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v4-demo-4hrqs?fontsize=14)

So I am using react-router-dom to create Single Page Application and I created standard navigation between two pages (components Page1 and Page2).

Problem is that every time I switch between pages then useEffect hook (with empty array as second argument) is called (on demo you can see it in console).

I would want to fetchData for each component only once and reuse that data after, no matter if user will switch between pages. Is there possibility to do it without checking some conditions inside useEffect function? It's a little confusing to me, because useEffect [] should run only once for component and it's not a case.

Comment: @Rajesh no, that's wrong. An empty array means it will only run when the component mounts, and that's it. It will be called again if the component is unmounted, then mounted again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An empty deps array means that the `useEffect` will only be called each time the component is mounted. The `useEffect` is being called every time you change the page because the page component is being unmounted each time, then remounted when you visit it again. For example, try clicking the page 1 link twice. It will only log the message once, because the page is not being unmounted and remounted.

You could try to fix this problem by using the `useEffect` a level higher than the page, which would be your app component, and call your fetch there instead. However, I'm not sure that can be done with a class component, so you might have to use a function component instead.

Comment: another interesting way to see this behaviour would be to swap out the `Page2` from being passed to the component prop on the routes so they both render the `Page1` like `component={Page1}`, it's intrinsic to the Route components that they unmount when the path changes in that setup